# How merge the data of 2 table order by Date in Sqlite Database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, sqlite

I am working on I Phone app, In that I am using SQLITE database.

In  my Sqlite Database, There are 2 Table, tblCreditDetail and tblGiftDetail,

```
        (1) tblCreditDetail

        ID            Name              Date
         1             A                2012-04-01
         2             B                2012-03-31
         3             C                2012-03-30


        (2)tblGiftDetail

         ID            Name              Date
         4             D                2012-03-22
         5             E                2012-03-24
         6             F                2012-03-26
```

Now, I want get all data of tblGiftDetail and tblCreditDetail in One and Order By Date.

Please any one suggest me, How can I do that?

Comment: `select * from (select * from tblcreditdetail union select * from tblgiftdetail) order by date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
SELECT ID,Name,Date FROM tblCreditDetail
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,Name,Date FROM tblGiftDetail
ORDER BY Date
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT * FROM tblCreditDetail )
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tblGiftDetail)
ORDER BY Date;
```

Use above Query.. Condition is that the schema of two tables must be the same.